# button to close entire browser using javascript not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

Closing entire browser windows using Javascript works fin on Desktop but not working on mobile device.
My code :

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

Comment: I am amazed that even works on desktops in modern browsers....

Comment: @epascarello why shouldn't you be able to close a windows opened by yourself?

Comment: nice question, it's web game . i need close button to close entire browser and redirect to play store, the redirection code is ok , but closing browser not working

Comment: @epascarello  That's what I thought, so tried it in Chrome from a script and get -> `test:1 Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.`  So what browser is the OP using I wonder?